# Create grid with knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Let's say we have an observable array of N+1 elements. What i would like to achive is to build 3 by X grid with buttons from these elements. Like phone keypad or something like this.

What i have done so far is created a table with foreach and if in it:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: tableList">
<!-- ko if: isEof($index())  -->
        <tr>
<!-- /ko -->
            <td><button data-bind="text: name"></button></td>
<!-- ko if: isEof($index())  -->
        </tr>
<!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

isEof() function should determine by list index wether we have already 3  elements rendered. If yes, then it will render  tags. Also if index is 0, then it also renders  elements.
This is the code of the function:

```
function TableItem(data){
    this.id=ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name=ko.observable(data.name);
    this.isEof = function(index){
        if(index ==0){
            return true;
        }else{
            if((index+3) % 3 === 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i'm facing two problems with this setup.

1) With these if blocks enabled, button name binding does not work. When i remove ko if blocks, it will be rendered correctly.

2) ko if statements does not seem to work correctly. It will render out only those  lines, where  is also allowed to render.

I've made JSFiddle sample of my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/kpihus/3Lw7xjae/2/

Comment: Ok, i allready noticed my problem. When i have third element for example, then i'll render <tr> and </tr> for that same <td> element, so other cells are not between <tr> and </tr>. Altough i'm not sure yet, how to fix this.

Comment: `kpilhus` you can check the answer posted now . Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `ko.computed` that converts your list of table items into an array of arrays:

```
var TableItem = function TableItem(data) {
    this.id   = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};

var Vm = function Vm() {
    this.tableItems  = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.columnCount = ko.observable(3);

    this.columns = ko.computed(function() {
        var columns     = [],
            itemCount   = this.tableItems().length,
            begin       = 0;

        // we use begin + 1 to compare to length, because slice 
        // uses zero-based index parameters
        while (begin + 1 < itemCount) {
            columns.push( this.tableItems.slice(begin, begin + this.columnCount()) );
            begin += this.columnCount();
        }

        return columns;

    // don't forget to set `this` inside the computed to our Vm
    }, this);
};

vm = new Vm();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
    vm.tableItems.push(new TableItem({
        id: i,
        name: "name: " + i
    }));
}
```

This way, you can display your table by nesting two `foreach` bindings:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: columns, as: 'column' }">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: column">
            <td>
                <button data-bind="text: name">A</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/3Lw7xjae/4/)

If you haven't worked with [`ko.computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) before, they track whatever observables are accessed inside of them — in this case, `this.tableItems` and `this.columnCount` —, and whenever one of them changes, they run again and produce a new result.

`this.columns` takes our array of table items

```
[TableItem, TableItem, TableItem, TableItem, TableItem, TableItem]
```

and groups them by `this.columnCount` into

```
[[TableItem, TableItem, TableItem], [TableItem, TableItem, TableItem]]
```

Comment: `janfoeh` well i posted a answer but in that can i avoid passing `root` from view ? is there a way i can get parent array inside `isEof ` function ? tried contextFor & dataFor i get undefined there . I like to make my view cleaner .Thanks

Comment: @supercool whenever you find yourself juggling around with scopes too much, chances are your asking the wrong object the wrong questions — an individual `TableItem` in itself doesn't know whether it is the third item in a the list of table items. Instead of trying to fix that by giving it access to the scope as you did here, why not ask the parent object — the view model here — that already has access to the list and can figure it out? As for the `undefined`, did you try `dataFor` or `ko.dataFor`?

Comment: i tried that but `vm.tableList`  gives me undefined . where as `ko.dataFor()` too gives me undefined . i don't quite get why dataFor wont work ? does it limited to click where we get `this`to pass as param . you can try on my fiddle to see the issue . Thanks again

Comment: `ko.dataFor` expects an HTML element as its parameter. Where did you call `ko.dataFor` from?

Comment: inside `self.isEof` i tried accessing that as i need that parent array list . present i am getting via root as parameter to function .

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this by simply passing `$root` which will have `tableList` and do the looping in simple way .

**View Model:**

```
function TableItem(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.pickarray = ko.observableArray();
    self.isEof = function (index, root) {
        if (index === 0) {
            self.pickarray(root.tableList().slice(index, index + 3));
            return true;
        } else if ((index + 3) % 3 === 0) {
            self.pickarray(root.tableList().slice(index, index + 3));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

var vm = function () {
    this.tableList = ko.observableArray();
    for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
        this.tableList.push(new TableItem({
            id: i,
            name: "name: " + i
        }));
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

**View :**

```
<table data-bind="foreach:tableList">
    <tr data-bind="if:isEof($index(),$root)">
        <!-- ko foreach: pickarray -->
        <td>
            <button data-bind="text: id"></button>
        </td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Trick here is very simple we just need to conditionally fill `pickarray` which does the job for us .

Working Fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/pxgvvqhk/)**